# R.java error. dont know where is came from. dont know how to fix it

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am creating an android application and when changing some of the code and going to run it i got told that there was an error in the application's R.Java file. i do no know where this error came from and i do not seem to be able to modify it.

the code inside the R.Java is

```
public final class R {
    public static final class array {
    public static final int races_array=0x7f040000;
}
public static final class attr {
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
    public static final int logo=0x7f020001;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int 1=0x7f060007;//this line has the error 
    public static final int BMI=0x7f06001f;
    public static final int Cdate=0x7f060005;
    public static final int Current=0x7f060006;
    public static final int Days=0x7f06001e;
    public static final int activity=0x7f06001b;
    public static final int advice=0x7f060004;
    public static final int cals=0x7f060022;
    public static final int cheight=0x7f060013;
    public static final int choice=0x7f060019;
    public static final int code=0x7f06001d;
    public static final int cweight=0x7f06000a;
    public static final int date=0x7f060020;
    public static final int dateDisplay=0x7f060008;
    public static final int details=0x7f06001c;
    public static final int eheight=0x7f060011;
    public static final int eweight=0x7f060012;
    public static final int get=0x7f06000d;
    public static final int goal=0x7f060025;
    public static final int group=0x7f060023;
    public static final int newheight=0x7f060017;
    public static final int newweight=0x7f060016;
    public static final int nweight=0x7f06000c;
    public static final int out=0x7f06000e;
    public static final int out_text=0x7f060002;
    public static final int pass=0x7f060018;
    public static final int pickDate=0x7f060009;
    public static final int progress=0x7f06001a;
    public static final int start=0x7f060003;
    public static final int step=0x7f060001;
    public static final int steps=0x7f060021;
    public static final int t1=0x7f06000f;
    public static final int t2=0x7f060010;
    public static final int textView1=0x7f06000b;
    public static final int textView2=0x7f060024;
    public static final int textView3=0x7f060014;
    public static final int textView4=0x7f060015;
    public static final int tv=0x7f060000;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity=0x7f030000;
    public static final int advice=0x7f030001;
    public static final int choice=0x7f030002;
    public static final int convert=0x7f030003;
    public static final int main=0x7f030004;
    public static final int notes_row=0x7f030005;
    public static final int progress=0x7f030006;
    public static final int splash=0x7f030007;
}
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f050001;
        public static final int hello=0x7f050000;
        public static final int race_elf=0x7f050003;
        public static final int race_goblin=0x7f050007;
        public static final int race_halfling=0x7f050006;
        public static final int race_human=0x7f050005;
        public static final int race_orc=0x7f050002;
        public static final int race_troll=0x7f050004;
    }
}
```

i do not know if this helps anyone but i just want to know what created this error and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an id somewhere defined as `@+id/1`. `1` does not make for a valid Java identifier, hence the error. For that same reason, one cannot create ids or resources which name starts with a number, or contains spaces, or matches a reserved keyword.

Comment: Thank you. i know exactly where that is. i will accept your answer when i can